# Minimum requirements Azure IoT Hub

Tags: azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

Does someone know the bare minimum required for a device to connect to the Azure IoT Hub and to send and receive messages (in terms of memory usage, processing power etc.). Or is this really case-specific?

I couldn't find a conclusive answer on the web. Does someone have experience with this?

Many thanks!

Comment: You can use AMQP, MQTT or HTTPS to send messages. MQTT is quite light and doesn't impose much requirements. But this question is very hard to answer objectively.

Comment: Was afraid it would be something like that indeed. Haven't tried looking at the specific protocols, so I will give that a try. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does someone know the bare minimum required for a device to connect to
>   the Azure IoT Hub and to send and receive messages (in terms of memory
>   usage, processing power etc.).

As @juunas pointed out, it is hard to say precisely.

But you can check from the following two aspects(I assume you mean devices that communicate directly with Azure IoT Hub)：

1. Using Azure IoT SDKs, the device needs to [be capable of establishing an IP connection, support TLS,  have at least 64KB of RAM ...](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdks#os-platforms-and-hardware-compatibility)
2. Using REST api, the device can connect to the Azure IoT Hub and to send and receive messages [directly over the Internet from any application that can send an HTTPS request and receive an HTTPS response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/).

Comment: These links also help a bit more to understand. I figured it was hard to pinpoint. Nevertheless, thanks for your help!

Comment: For the specific case of the SDK for the C langage, the prerequisites (first link of this answer) are currently available here: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c#os-platforms-and-hardware-compatibility

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing like system/set-up requirements for Azure IoT Hub so there's no specific document from Microsoft talking about this topic. Depending on your target application you can pick the device, as all descent embedded devices can act as IoT device for Azure.

You can take a look at [Azure Certified IoT device catalogue](https://catalog.azureiotsuite.com/) and find out whether particular device is listed under that.

Answer (score 1):

MS has published 2 Whitepapers on this. You may find this useful

1. [Evaluating Your IOT Security](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/3/9/D3948E3C-D5DC-474E-B22F-81BA8ED7A446/Evaluating_Your_IOT_Security_whitepaper_EN_US.pdf)
2. [The right secure hardware for your IoT deployment](http://download.microsoft.com/download/C/0/5/C05276D6-E602-4BB1-98A4-C29C88E57566/The_right_secure_hardware_for_your_IoT_deployment_EN_US.pdf)